# How to call multiple angularjs service calls from within nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am making a simple sports goods shopping app in AngularJs.

I am in a situation where I have three nested ng-repeats.

**First loop:** Get the brand name. I have written angularjs service that calls the rest endpoint to fetch the lists of brands (Adidas, Yonex, Stiga, etc). I am calling this service as soon as the page(controller) gets loaded.

**Second loop:** For each brand, I want to display the category of products they are offering. Inside this loop, I want to execute a function/service that will take the brand name as input and get all the categories for the brand. For this, I also have an angularjs service that calls the rest endpoint to fetch the list of categories for a given brand name.

**Third loop:** For each brand and category, I want to display the products in that category. Inside this loop, I want to execute a function that will take the brand name and category as input and get all the products in that category. I an angularjs service call which will call the rest endpoint to fetch the products given the brand name and category.

**Sample data set:**

```
Adidas
-----T-Shirts
----------V-Neck
----------RoundNeck
-----Shoes
----------Sports Shoes
----------LifeStyle Shoes
Yonex
-----Badminton Racquet
----------Cabonex
----------Nanospeed
-----Shuttlecocks
----------Plastic
----------Feather
Stiga
-----Paddle
----------Procarbon
----------Semi-carbon
-----Ping Pong Balls
----------Light Weight
----------Heavy Weight
```

Please note that because of some constraints I cannot have a domain object on the REST side to mimic the data structure shown above.

I want to display the above data in a tree-like fashion (something on the same lines as shown above possibly with expand/collapse options).
Below are the code snippets.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('SportsShoppingApp.controllers').controller('sportsController', ['sportsService', '$scope', function (sportsService, $scope) {

        $scope.brands = [];
        $scope.categories = [];
        $scope.products = {};

        $scope.getBrands = function () {
            sportsService.getBrands()
                .then(loadBrands, serviceError);
        };

    var loadBrands = function(response) {
        $scope.brands= response.data;
    };


        $scope.getCategories = function(brand) {
            sportsService.getCategories(brand)
                .then(loadCategories, serviceError);
        };

    var loadCategories = function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
        };


        $scope.getProducts = function(brand, category) {
            sportsService.getProducts(brand, category)
                .then(loadProducts, serviceError);
        };

    var loadProducts = function (response) {
            $scope.products = response.data;
        };

        var serviceError = function (errorMsg) {
            console.log(errorMsg);
        };

    $scope.getBrands();

    }]);
}());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sportsHeader" class="col-md-3">
            <div ng-repeat="brand in brands.data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">{{brand}}</div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="category in categories.data" ng-init="getCategories(brand)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">{{category}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="product in products.data" ng-init="getProducts(brand, category)">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">{{product}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use the above HTML, only the brand names are displayed on the UI. The categories and their corresponding products are not displayed. I know that there is some overlapping that is happening. I am not sure if I am doing it the right way. I might be completely wrong with my approach. I am new to AngularJS. I want to know how to loop in nested ng-repeat so that each ng-repeat could call an angularjs service and also I want to display the data in the tree fashion as shown above. Can someone help me here?

Comment: I think you need $q.all()

Comment: The `loadBrands` function populates `$scope.categories` and the `loadCategories` function also populates `$scope.categories`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is a type. I have rectified it.

Comment: **DON'T** use `ng-init` for this!  `ng-init` is a directive, which has a priority, which means you cannot guarantee the timing of it's results.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `ng-init`s have to be placed on separate tags to the `ng-repeat`s:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sportsHeader" class="col-md-3">
            <div ng-repeat="brand in brands.data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">{{brand}}</div>
                </div>
                <div ng-init="getCategories(brand)">
                    <div ng-repeat="category in categories.data">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">{{category}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-init="getProducts(brand, category)">
                            <div ng-repeat="product in products.data">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">{{product}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might have to juggle your bootstrap classes around also, moving `ng-init` is only to fix the angular part.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `ng-init` directives outside of the `ng-repeat` to which they provide data.

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sportsHeader" class="col-md-3">
            <!-- MOVE init of categories here -->
            <div ng-repeat="brand in brands.data"  ng-init="getCategories(brand)">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">{{brand}}</div>
                </div>
                <!-- MOVE init of products here -->
                <div ng-repeat="category in categories.data"  ng-init="getProducts(brand, category)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">{{category}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="product in products.data">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">{{product}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `ng-init` directive has a priority of 450; the `ng-repeat`, priority 1000. This means that when they are on the same element `ng-init` executes **after** the `ng-repeat` directive. The `ng-repeat` for `categories.data` won't execute its `ng-init` until it has a category. Thus its `ng-init` can't be used to populate the `categories` array.

---

> Quick question. Is my approach correct ?

The approach works but it violates the [Zen of Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction#the-zen-of-angularjs) and the principles of an [MV* Model View Whatever](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2) framework.

> ### The model is the [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)
>
> Because the view is just a projection of the model, the controller is completely separated from the view and unaware of it. This makes testing a snap because it is easy to test your controller in isolation without the view and the related DOM/browser dependency.
>
> [--AngularJS Developer Guide -- Data-Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)

Having the `ng-repeat` and `ng-init` directives build the model creates a dependency that makes testing and debugging difficult. (As witnessed by this question.)

My advice is to learn how to build the model by [chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) and using [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: Quick question. Is my approach correct ? Since it is two way data binding, dont you think, by the time all the nested ng-repeats are complete, the tree will show only the last brand, last category and the last product each time.